# How can I use GetView and GetWidget with their bindings using an indexed stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

so I'm using Getx package, I'm using GetView and GetWidget instead of StatelessWidget so it finds the controllers I bind to them from a separate bindings file I want without the boilerplate of writing `Get.find<T>();` for each screen.

the package was made so that the bindings will actually work when using route managers like `Get.to()`, `Get.off()`...

in my case I'm using `Indexed Stack` to show those views, here is a sample :

```
IndexedStack(
        index: currentScreenIndex,
        children: <Widget>[
          ScreenExample(),
          ScreenExample()
          ScreenExample()
          ScreenExample()
        ])
```

when navigating between those indexed screens we're not opening/closing pages, we just navigate between them, so the bindings don't actually work for each screen

I want that when navigating in those screens, the bindings work like if we use `Get.to()`...
so the bindings actually work normally, I want to still use `GetView` and `GetWidget` so extending just StatelessWidget and writing `Get.put()` for each page is not possible because I have too many pages

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: try use pageviewbuilder

Answer (score -1):

[documentation:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html)

> Indexed Stack : A Stack that shows a single child from a list of children.

The screen will not navigated, `IndexedStack` will change the children based on index selected.

if you want to bind  and navigate the screen, dont use `indexedstack`